# Best approach to elevate method visibility in a descendant class

Tags: delphi

Best way to elaborate on the question is to give an example of what I'm trying to do...

I define a "base class":

```
TMyBaseClass = class(TPersistent)
protected
  procedure Foo(const AValue: String); virtual;
  // more methods here (many more in fact)
end;
```

I now define a descendant class:

```
TMyDescendantClass = class(TMyBaseClass)
public
  procedure Foo(const AValue: String); override;
  // etc. for all desired methods I wish to elevate into Public
end;
```

The problem here is that I then have to redefine the method "Foo" for TMyDescendantClass to pass the call up the chain to TMyBaseClass:

```
procedure TMyDescendantClass.Foo(const AValue: String);
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

This is a waste of space! I'm wondering if anyone knows of any way to negate the need to reimplement the method and acll "inherited".

An ideal solution would look something like:

```
TMyDescendantClass = class(TMyBaseClass)
public
  procedure Foo(const AValue: String); elevated;
  // etc. for all desired methods
end;
```

Obviously this is hypothetical, and I know the keyword "elevated" does not exist in the Delphi language. Is there a keyword with the same effect I just don't know about?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you changing the visibility? if you set it in the ancestor as public you won't have to override and the ancestor implementation would be used.

Comment: @az01 I'm defining the methods in the base class as "protected", then elevating the necessary methods in their respective descendant classes because not all methods apply to all descendants (certainly from a Public perspective)

Comment: "not all methods apply to all descendants" has a faint whiff of design flaws

Comment: "not all methods apply to all descendants (certainly from a Public perspective)" -- if that is true, then you need to redesign your class structure, as you aren't following OOP's SOLID principles.

Comment: To clarify: There are overloaded versions of these methods, where the overload adds a few steps to the same routine....

procedure TBaseClass.Foo(const AValue: String);
begin
  // do something with the value
end;

procedure TBaseClass.Foo(const AKey: String; const AValue: String);
begin
  // do something with the KEY
  Foo(AValue); // to do something with the value
end;

Comment: In one of the descendant classes I want it to expose Foo(AValue) as public, in the other descendant class it wants to expose Foo(AKey, AValue) as public but NOT Foo(AValue).

Since Foo(AKey, AValue) just performs some additional work before the standard "base behaviour" of Foo(AValue), it makes sense to define both methods in the base class in the Protected section, then elevate each method appropriately in separate descendants to be used by external code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such keyword. You can trivially [change the visibility of a property by redeclaring it with a new visibility level](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Property_Overrides_and_Redeclarations). But there is nothing analogous for a method.

Comment: That's what I thought... figured it was worth asking just in case someone knew of a "newer" language feature I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @LaKraven Such language feature would be going into the wrong direction, according to SOLID principles. So I hope it won't be added - but we have seen class helpers feature, which is just a big OOP design breaker IMHO.

Comment: @Arnaud: I don't see how exposing behaviour lower in a class hierarchy for the public to consume directly as well instead of "just" for the consumption of derived classes goes against SOLID? Isn't adding/exposing features in derived classes the point of deriving?

Comment: @MarjanVenema Exactly! The idea is that some derived classes will expose the methods publicly, others cannot... but all of these derived classes will make use of those methods internally.

Comment: @LaKraven: sorry, but while exposing stuff in derived classes doesn't go against SOLID in my opinion, having a base class with methods that are only _applicable_ for a subset of derived classes, not for all, is an alltogether other matter. I am still pondering your clarification comment on your question though... I understand what you want to do, just don't have the time now to consider the consequences wrt SOLID.

Comment: @MarjanVenema The methods aren't ONLY applicable to for a subset... the methods defined in the base class are applicable to all (used internally), but only want to be directly accessible from external code for certain descendants.

Comment: @LaKraven: ok, then I was "led astray" :) by your response to az01's comment on your question.

Answer (score 4):

Have you heard of the *protected hack*?

In your case you simply create a derived class in the same unit where you want to call the protected methods like this:

```
TMyDescendantClass = class(TMyBaseClass);
```

Then, to call your protected method:

```
TMyDescendentClass(myObject).Foo;
```

You can go further and avoid typecasting by hiding the original class:

```
TMyBaseClass = class(UnitName.TMyBaseClass);
```

Then, it's simply:

```
myObject.Foo;
```

Comment: You would have to do this in every unit that used the class. It doesn't seem an improvement on an override.

Comment: It's definitely an improvement over reimplementing the methods. That's one line of code per unit.

Comment: More detailed [explanation by Zarko Gajic](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/l/aa082603a.htm)